# Top questions show "wrong" bounty count

Tags: bug, bounties, expired-bounty

On the front page of the site, the total of bounties is accounting for those on grace period, but they're not actually shown in the page.

Ask Different's homepage:

[image: ask different]

Featured questions page:

[image]

---

Stack Overflow em Português homepage:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Featured questions page:

[image]

---

I found that the missing ones using `hasnotice:1` as search query. I think either the number should be adjusted or keep the questions on grace period showing up on those pages.

Comment: No, I don't have ignored tags at SOPT nor Ask Different. Also, no browser extension running and same behavior on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I am unable to currently reproduce this behaviour, so voting to close.

Comment: @Luuklag - please don't edit so many posts at once - it fills the front page and makes it much more difficult to see new posts, or ones which actually need attention

Comment: @RoryAlsop it were only 10 questions, so no real flood there. Sometimes housekeeping just needs to be done.

Comment: For some of them it seems the edit may not have been correct. I won't roll them back, but did you agree them with other members of the community ? For some searching on grace-period is likely to help more users.